# Mechanism used to Claim at risk addresses

Tags: security, address-reuse, foundation

What Mechanism was used to Claim the at risk addresses? (from the September and October events) How Is it possible to move anothers address into an amalgamated foundation address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The foundation has used snapshots in order to move at risk funds from vulnerable addresses to new addresses.

A snapshot, currently, is completely manual, and is basically a database of addresses and how much IOTA is stored at each of them that every node must agree to load. As the nodes are cooperative with the devs right now, they are willing to accept the modified snapshot database which allows the devs to move at risk funds to a single pooled address. Therefore it requires some cooperation from the node holders.